# JS check if value exists

Tags: javascript

For some reason my JS is not reacting as I thought it would.
The submit button is disabled at page load.

When en value is entered in the datum field the class should change and submit button should enabled. Neither is happening.

It seems an standard code but still an issue?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('form_submit').disabled = true;
}

function validate() {
  if (document.getElementById('datum').value == false) {
    document.getElementById('div_datum').className = "col-md-2 input-group has-warning";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('div_datum').className = "col-md-2 input-group has-success";
    document.getElementById('form_submit').disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="datum" class="col-md-2 form-label">Datum toolbox</label>
    <div class="col-md-2 input-group has-warning" id="div_datum">
      <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="datum" name="datum" onkeyup="validate()" onclick="validate()"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Verplicht veld"></span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="form_submit">Verstuur</button>

</div>
```

Comment: I've converted your code block into a Stack Snippet. It enables the button when I type in the field. Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: How are you hiding the button? There is nothing in your example that hides or shows the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
if (document.getElementById('datum').value == false)
```

will branch into the attached `if` block on a couple of values (for instance, if I type 0, not just when the value is blank (because `"0" == false` is, bizarrely, `true`). A more reliable check for a blank value is:

```
if (!document.getElementById('datum').value)
```

That will branch in only if `value` is `""`. (You may or may not want to add `.trim()` to `value` if you want to clear leading and trailing whitespace.)

Separately, I can't help but notice that your `validate` function never sets `disabled` to `true`, only `false`. What if I type something, then backspace over it? You probably want to disable the button again. So:

```
function validate() {
  if (document.getElementById('datum').value == false) {
    document.getElementById('div_datum').className = "col-md-2 input-group has-warning";
    document.getElementById('form_submit').disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('div_datum').className = "col-md-2 input-group has-success";
    document.getElementById('form_submit').disabled = false;
  }
}
```

or a bit more refactoring:

```
function validate() {
  var invalid = !document.getElementById('datum').value.trim();
  document.getElementById('div_datum').className = "col-md-2 input-group " + (invalid ? "has-warning" : "has-success");
  document.getElementById('form_submit').disabled = invalid;
}
```

---

Note that [`String.prototype.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) was added in ES 5.1 (June 2011), so it doesn't exist in obsolete browsers like IE8, although it can be polyfilled; see the link for a polyfill.